# Bootstrap horizontal menu with fade effect on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fadein, fadeout

I have the bootstrap horizontal menu which is working on hover. Is it possible to add the fade effect? I wass trying with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`, but it mees up the menu.

Here is the example: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hwTprkQlQe)

Comment: can you give an example how it should work? with an example site?

Comment: Something similar to main menu on this site: http://www.ue.katowice.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it would be more consistent with Bootstrap if you use tabs in the top menu:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active pull-right" id="one">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right submenu" role="navigation">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav in" id="one-nav">
            <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade pull-right" id="two">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right submenu" role="navigation">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav in" id="two-nav">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade pull-right" id="three">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right submenu" role="navigation">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav in" id="three-nav">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then just trigger a click on hover:

```
$('a','.nav-tabs > li').hover(function(){ 
  $(this).trigger('click'); 
});

// The following addresses the problem listed in the comment below
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $('.tab-pane').not($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('active');
});
```

See the [bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/2v2U3CWmhQ).

Comment: it works quite well except one thing - when you move fast the cursor from left to right or right to left on tab list - sometime three submenu is active in one time

Comment: You're right. Seems like a minor bug in Bootstrap. Added a check in the JavaScript above to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

JQUERY

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').hover(function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle=collapse]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
  $($(this).data('target')).collapse('show').fadeIn(fast);
});

$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $('.collapse').not(this).removeClass('in').fadeOut(fast);
});
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom:-1px;
    border-radius:0;
}

#submenu {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.collapsing {
    display:none;

}
```

The only thing I have changed is that is fading in fast and fading out fast ...

Please for more adapting and the properties of fadeIn / fadeOut property here is a great link

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/